# Java Bufferedimage setRgb getRgb, 2 different results

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d

i´m trying to convert a image into a matrix and convert it back, but the 2 pictures are different:
convert it into a matrix:

```
 public int[][] getMatrixOfImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    int width = bufferedImage.getWidth(null);
    int height = bufferedImage.getHeight(null);
    int[][] pixels = new int[width][height];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            pixels[i][j] = bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
        }
    }

    return pixels;
}
```

and convert it back into a bufferedImage:

```
   public BufferedImage matrixToBufferedImage(int[][] matrix) {
    int width=matrix[0].length;
    int height=matrix.length;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {

            int pixel=matrix[i][j] <<24|matrix[i][j] <<16|matrix[i][j]<<8|matrix[i][j] ;
            bufferedImage.setRGB(i, j, pixel);
        }
    }
    return bufferedImage;

}
```

with this result:

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/5464/mt8a.png

Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid getRGB/setRGB for performance reasons (each call makes expensive color space calculations), it is possible to get to the array behind the image through the Raster of the BufferedImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you do

```
int pixel=matrix[i][j] <<24|matrix[i][j] <<16|matrix[i][j]<<8|matrix[i][j];
```

instead of just

```
int pixel=matrix[i][j];
```

?

Comment: it´s the solution, i´m gonna marked, when i have the permission.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to know